# Can NetworkMapService in Corda have arbitrary information about the node?

Tags: distributed-system, corda

Is it possible to query NetworkMapService to get the list of all the nodes in the network to use it in the flow logic?

Is it also possible to register arbitrary information or meta data to the NetworkMapService about the node?

The use-case is to find out the nodes with certain responsibilities or abilities and send out request to those nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a list of all the nodes on the network as follows:

```
val allNodes = serviceHub.networkMapCache.allNodes
```

Nodes cannot register additional metadata with the network map. In previous versions, nodes could advertise "services" they ran - such as an oracle service or a regulatory service. This is now being deprecated. In the future, we expect that you will be able to pass a config file to the node telling it which nodes to use for which services. In the meantime, you have to specify the node you want to use explicitly by name (possibly as an argument to a flow).